# Is it mandatory to use contractions in tag questions and the like?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, questions, contractions, tag-questions

Example 1:

> The weather is hot, isn't it?

vs.:

> The weather is hot, is it not?

Example 2:

> Aren't you going to study tonight?

vs.:

> Are you not going to study tonight?

Apart from convenience in pronuncation, how do the above versions differ (contraction vs. full form)?

Answer (score 1):

The noun subjects in your example full-form sentences are in the wrong location. A native English speaker would never say "is not it?", but rather "is it not?". The same goes for example 2 where the correct form would be "Are you not...."

The corrected subject-verb full-form versions can be a little awkward (when placed at the end of a sentence, this phrase structure feels particularly old fashioned), but they aren't wrong. I wouldn't even think twice if someone said "Are you not going to ____?" Meaning wise, there's no difference between your examples with and without the contractions.

Answer (score 0):

They  may not   differ  in  meaning.

The  last  sentence should  be:

Are you  not  going  to  study to  night?

The  question   tags  are  usually  contractions.

In  speech  we  say    Aren' t  you  going  instead  of   Are  you  not  going?